# Jenkins - Send warning statistics by email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I configured jenkins to build, and test my .NET application. As part of build pipeline, I set up warnings-ng plugin to analyze warnings and Email extension for sending emails. Jenkins can send emails with simple text and also Warnings-ng works and I have warning tab in jenkins with charts and informations about warnings.

My manager wants to have these statistics in email. Is it possible to configure jenkins to send warning statistics via email? I want to include in email text total count of warning, count of fixed warnings, etc.

I search in documentation but I did not find way how to include warnings count in similar way like build number or other variables. I would like to know if there is easier way than scraping content of jenkins web site and parsing information from it.

Just for information, here is part of my pipeline responsible for analyze warnings and sending emails.

```
stage('Warning') {
  steps {
    recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tools:[msBuild()]
  }
}
post {  
  always {  
    echo 'Build finished'  
             emailext body: "Build completed \n Project: ${env.JOB_NAME} \n Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} \n URL of build: ${env.BUILD_URL}", 
             subject: "Build finished: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", 
             to: "aaa@company.com";  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> My manager wants to have these statistics in email. Is it possible to
> configure jenkins to send warning statistics via email? I want to
> include in email text total count of warning, count of fixed warnings,
> etc.

As far as my knowledge goes, warnings-ng has so called "[Tokens](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#token-macro-support)".

Via these Tokens you can access the amount of warnings with different filters.

*Example:*

```
emailext body: '''    
Total amount of warnings ${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT}
Amount of new warnings (since the last build i guess) ${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT, type="NEW"} '''
```

I hope the link and the examples can solve your question. Have a great day.

**Edit:** For the Tokens to work, you need (as stated in the documentation) the [Token Macro Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/?msclkid=c3b00c8fb0d811ecaf80640356c9e6cf) for Jenkins